# How to use logical OR operator in node-orm2 for finding records from database?

Tags: node.js, node-orm2

I am working on the [Node ORM.](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2)

I want to find the records based on logical OR condition.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass following array in the find method of the Person model.

```
Person.find({or:[{col1: 1}, {col2: 2}]}, function(err, res) {
  // res is Person where col1 == 1 or col2 == 2
});
```